# Proving that a preorder traversal of a rooted tree $T(V, E)$ is $O(\lvert V \rvert)$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, recurrences

**Definition:**

Let $T(V, E)$ be a rooted tree with root $r$.

If $T$ has no other vertices, then the root by itself constitutes the *preorder traversal* of $T$.

If $\lvert V \rvert > 1$, let $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_k$ denote the subtrees of $T$ from left to right. The *preorder traversal* of $T$ first visits $r$ and then traverses the vertices of $T_1$ in preorder, then the vertices of $T_2$ in preorder, and so on until the vertices of $T_k$ are traversed in preorder.

**Question:**

How does one prove that the above definition implies $O(\lvert V \rvert)$? Since $T$ is a tree, $\lvert E \rvert = \lvert V \rvert - 1$ and so showing that each vertex and edge is visited a constant number of times would do it. This is intuitively obvious as this is exactly the purpose of a preorder traversal -- to visit each vertex. But how does one prove this formally?

Comment: Isn't this a trivial induction on $|V|$?

Comment: Your proposed strategy, counting visits, will work fine once you define visits. As it stands, your description of the algorithm just produces the list of all vertices, in order of first visit; that has length $|V|$, which is $O(|V|)$ but isn't what you meant. Define what it means for the preorder traversal to traverse an edge. It should then be  easy to prove that each edge is traversed exactly twice (once going away from the root and once going back).

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove a special case (you can generalize it), when the tree $T$ is a full k-ary tree with $r$ levels ($l=0,\ldots, r-1$, with each level having $k^l$ nodes), with total $n=\frac{k^r-1}{k-1}$ nodes. Then we have the following recurrence relation w.r.t. the time complexity $T(n)$:

$T(n) = kT(\frac{n-1}{k}) + 1$ (since each of the children nodes $T_1 \ldots T_k$ has $\frac{n-1}{k}$ nodes each)

$=k^2T(\frac{n-k-1}{k^2})+k+1$

$\ldots$

$=k^{r-1}T\left(\frac{n-k^{r-2}-k^{r-3}-\ldots 1}{k^{r-1}}\right)+(k^{r-2}+k^{r-3}+\ldots+k^2+k+1)$

$=k^{r-1}T\left(\frac{\frac{k^r-1}{k-1}-\frac{k^{r-1}-1}{k-1}}{k^{r-1}}\right)+(\frac{k^{r-1}-1}{k-1})$ (since $n=\frac{k^r-1}{k-1}$)

$=k^{r-1}T(1)+(\frac{k^{r-1}-1}{k-1})$

$=k^{r-1}.1+\frac{k^{r-1}-1}{k-1}$  (since T(1)=1)

$=\frac{k^r-1}{k-1}$

$=n= O(n) = O(|V|)$

It basically means you need to traverse every node once to traverse the tree